# REST Resource look up service

Tags: rest, lookup

Imagine an application where there are multiple RESTFUL servers exist with different resources.

When a client makes a resource request, currently a blocking call is made such that the resource request is relayed from Server to Server until the resource is found at some Server. Which is very time consuming . Now all the clients are run in constrained environment and Servers are moderately powerful.

Is there a way to do REST resource lookup service to avoid long blocking calls ?

Answer (score 0):

Client should know where to look for a resource without relaying in a happy flow. So build the logic for getting a resource in the client.

**Solution 1:**
Client A has a list of all the resource servers and has a directory to know which resource is on which server.

**Solution 2:**
Client A does not know anything so it will query proxy server B which does the look up. This server B has a directory to map a particular resource to a specific server.

Server B will then query Resource server C/D/E/F etc. depending on the resource. They will respond to Server B.

Server B sends the requested resource to Client A

**Update 1:** Since you do not have control over your clients, go with solution 2 where B acts as a client in relation to your resource servers. As stated before either use a dictionary where each specific resource points to a particular server or use [consistent hashing](http://www.tomkleinpeter.com/2008/03/17/programmers-toolbox-part-3-consistent-hashing/). Since I do not know what language you are using I have no idea whether there is an existing library for you to use.But there are [so many already](https://www.google.nl/search?q=consistent%20hashing%20library&oq=consistent%20hashing%20library&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.8631j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) so probably it will fit your needs.

Comment: i want to build exactly, "where to look" service .

Comment: Update the answer. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Solution 1 is not for me , since the clients are very very resource constrained. Solution 2 is what i was looking for , but i want if there is something available already that can be used off shelf. something built on DHT for REST

Comment: There are a lot of implementation for consistent hashing in different languages. Use solution 2 with consistent hashing for server B (which acts like a client in relation to your resource servers)